# MariaDB is using more memory than the buffer allows - 4x more

Tags: mariadb

Help me out here brain trust, why is my MariaDB 10.2.27 using 4x more resident memory over the buffer?

```
MariaDB [(none) 10.2.27]>SELECT MAX_USED_MEMORY_GB, INNODB_BUFFER FROM
(SELECT ROUND((@@key_buffer_size + @@query_cache_size + @@tmp_table_size + @@innodb_buffer_pool_size + @@innodb_log_buffer_size + @@max_connections * 
(@@read_buffer_size + @@read_rnd_buffer_size + @@sort_buffer_size + @@join_buffer_size + @@binlog_cache_size + @@thread_stack + @@tmp_table_size))/power(1024,3),2) AS MAX_USED_MEMORY_GB)A, 
(SELECT ROUND(SUM(@@key_buffer_size + @@query_cache_size + @@tmp_table_size + @@innodb_buffer_pool_size + @@innodb_log_buffer_size + @@max_connections)/power(1024,3),2) AS INNODB_BUFFER)B;
+--------------------+---------------+
| MAX_USED_MEMORY_GB | INNODB_BUFFER |
+--------------------+---------------+
|              33.15 |          3.13 |
+--------------------+---------------+

Memory on the box:
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           565G        219G        4.2G        4.0G        341G        340G
Swap:          2.0G        833M        1.2G
```

From HTOP
[image]

Comment: Memory use per (cached) thread/connection would be my assumption. Find a better source for your sql. Some items like `key_buffer_size` and `tmp_table_size` can be per connection rather than a static amount.

Answer (score 2):

- You should be using Engine=InnoDB, not MyISAM.
- `key_buffer_size` is used only by MyISAM, so, after converting your tables to InnoDB, set that to only 30M.
- `tmp_table_size` and `max_heap_size` rarely come into play.  That is, they unnecessarily inflate the SUM.
- `query_cache_size` should be 0 -- it is an old device that is dying out.
- `innodb_buffer_pool_size` is the most important setting; it should be about 70% of *availlable* RAM.
- Some sizes need multiplying by `max_connections`, but even that is rarely accurate -- usually too high, sometimes too low.

etc.

The bottom line is that there is no good formula for memory usage.

Comment: The box has 500G of physical RAM. The buffer pool is set to 3 and as you can see by HTOP, I am using nearly 4x that amount. That's the concern, why is this DB using more than 4x the buffer pool?

Comment: htop can only see the entire size of the program, not individual items, such as the buffer_pool.